# SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED in aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I installed [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-msi-on-windows) on the Windows server 2007 32bit.

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.8.8 Python/2.7.9 Windows/2008Server
```

I configure `aws cli` using keys

Once I run below command to test AWS S3, I get this SSL error:

```
aws s3 ls
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

Please help to get rid of this basic error.

Answer (score 67):

If you want to use SSL and not have to specify the **--no-verify-ssl** option, then you need to set the **AWS_CA_BUNDLE** environment variable. e.g from PowerShell:

```
setx AWS_CA_BUNDLE "C:\Users\UserX\Documents\RootCert.pem"
```

The PEM file is a saved copy of the root certificate for the AWS endpoint you are trying to connect to.  To generate it, first export the certificate in DER format (For details on how to do this, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file)).  Then run the following command to convert to the PEM format:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in "C:\Users\UserX\Documents\RootCert.der" -out RootCert.pem
```

If you are using Powershell and not bash, then you will need to first install [openssl](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm).

For a full list of environment variables supported by the AWS CLI, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)

Comment: This is it: don't use --no-verify-ssl as it's unsafe, better trust your local network root certificate.

Comment: It worked with --no-verify-ssl for me, but not with --ca-bundle. The GUI for my s3 repository is https://<something>/_/s3brower, so I tried to export the certificate with :
`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <something>:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM > MyRootCertificate.pem`
Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Replying to my own comment : Warning: I got a list of certificates. **This command only export the first certificate of the list** to .pem format. In my case, it was the last certificate of the list that worked. I had to extract it manually to put it alone in a file before converting it to pem.

Comment: This *is* the solution. I was getting a similar error when connecting from my corporate network and accessing AWS services and getting Python to update the Certifi package.  Add these environment variables: AWS_CA_BUNDLE and
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE

Answer (score 46):

use this option with your cmd:

```
--no-verify-ssl
```

Comment: Using --no-verify-ssl is unsafe. This usually comes from security considerations by the network team in corporate environment, in which case trusing the root certificate is much better. See @Xcalibur 's answer.

Comment: This suggestion totally undermines the security provided by SSL... don't use this.

Comment: Disabling ssl is never a good idea. Should be used only under extreme necessity.

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if it's related to to the OP's issue, however, one of our devs had this issue this morning, turned out he was using Fiddler (on Windows), to debug other issues. After stopping Fiddler (which was intercepting https traffic), the issue was resolved.

Comment: If you have setup some kind of Mitm proxy (ex: Charles Proxy) on your development machine, don't forget to close it as well!

Comment: Life saver 7 years later!

Answer (score 7):

I added the certificate to C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\awscli\botocore\cacert.pem and it resolved the problem.

Comment: which certificate?

Comment: If you're in the corporate environment it will be the cert provided by your it team to add your proxy (that inspects you traffic). SSL connections will complain that your proxy is acting as a MITM unless you add its cert to the chain.

Comment: This worked for me for corporate proxies such as Zscaler. You have to add the Zscaler root certificate to mentioned pem file and launch new Terminal.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue on Windows 10. It happens to be due to the `aws cli` not reading the internet proxy setting from the Windows registry. Fixed same error by setting the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to the corporate internet proxy. Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: How and where did you do that?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is the issue I have faced. Your PC must be connected to the internet without any proxy in order to prevent this error.

Answer (score 5):

Mine was resolved with:

```
pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Comment: I cannot do this, because the pip SSL has the same problem  :(

Comment: @MikeF either your local certificates are old (e.g ubuntu updates them by:update-ca-certificates) OR your company is using tools like Netscope to track your activity. Such tools use custom certificates and traffic goes via the local proxy. You need to create a ticket with Security team to update their local certificates.

Answer (score 5):

My issue was our company's VPN. It worked after I disconnected from VPN

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue on Mac OSX in the company/corporate network. 
If you don't know the proxy URL Get it from your company's network administrator and configure with the following commands.

## Linux, macOS, or Unix

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:1234
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:1234
```

## Windows

```
$ set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:1234
$ set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:1234
```

[More information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-proxy.html)

Comment: did not work for me, I have no choice than --no-verify-ssl

Answer (score 3):

```
Linux:
$ export AWS_CA_BUNDLE="/data/ca-certs/ca-bundle.pem"

Windows:
PS C:\> setx AWS_CA_BUNDLE C:\data\ca-certs\ca-bundle.pem

$ aws s3 ls --ca-bundle "/data/ca-certs/ca-bundle.pem"
```

Comment: Your answer can be improved by explaining (1) what the commands do, (2) referencing to documentation that supports your answer, (3) properly formatting code snippets

Answer (score 2):

AWS already posted a clean solution for this, here it is:
Instead of hacking your system now the CLI supports you passing it a .pem file with the CA chain for it to communicate with your proxy:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-troubleshooting.html#tshoot-certificate-verify-failed

> To fix this, instruct the AWS CLI where to find your companies .pem file using the ca_bundle configuration file setting, --ca-bundle command line option, or the AWS_CA_Bundle environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this option would have been tried already but just putting it here for everyones reference:

when you have proxy added to your ec2 machines and it is in private subnet with a S3 vpc-endpoint attached. I was getting the same error.

Bypassing the proxy using no_proxy for the bucket as per : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint/

didn't help me and was still failing with the same error.

the only catch here was we need to add endpoint url which is s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com as below and it worked for me:

export NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254,s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

169.254.169.254 is used to access instance role credentials in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the ssl error for s3.

I recommend reinstalling the AWS CLI per the recommended steps and confirming that a proxy isn't the issue. Then locate your certificate (for example python -m certifi) and set the path using using the ca_bundle configuration file setting, --ca-bundle command line option, or the AWS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable. For example: export AWS_CA_BUNDLE="path to cacert.pem"

source - https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7552#issuecomment-1368027096

I  ran "python3 -m certi"   it gave the path as "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem"

Then I did
export AWS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem

this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by setting the proxy as follows:

```
$ set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:1234

$ set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:1234
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a AWS CLI command, you receive a "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_ VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed" error message. This is caused by the AWS CLI not trusting your proxy's certificate due to factors such as your proxy's certificate being self-signed, with your company set as the Certification Authority (CA). This prevents the AWS CLI from finding your companies CA root certificate in the local CA registry.

To fix this, instruct the AWS CLI where to find your companies .pem file using the ca_bundle configuration file setting, --ca-bundle command line option, or the AWS_CA_Bundle environment variable.

Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-troubleshooting.html#tshoot-certificate-verify-failed

Answer (score 0):

For me ec2 instance date was incorrect, after changing the date and time, fixed the problem.
Simply rebooted the ec2 instance

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a corporate computer. What worked for me in VSC is to set the proxy- support from "override" to "off".

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the below issue in the window os. when running this command in console "aws s3 ls --profile profile1".
ssl validation failed for https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ [errno 2] no such file or directory.

I followed the below step and my issue got resolved.
step-1. open the command prompt.
step-2. set AWS_CA_BUNDLE=C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\awscli\botocore\cacert.pem

Horray!.. done:)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and bent over backwards trying to figure out what certificate file to use. Turns out the issue was that I had the AWS region set incorrectly. Once that was corrected, my SSL verification went smoothly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually stop the SSL certificate verification using python (although it is not recommended and should only be done for debugging purpose). Add the following code before the block of code that's throwing the following error.

```
import ssl                                       
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem most likely caused by corporate proxy. In my case I was running the commands on AWS CLI behind proxy server and was getting certificate error. 
So to get around this I added ***--no-verify-ssl*** flag. Though this is a bad idea, I used this as a temporary solution to get the job done until it is resolved by the network team.

Answer (score -1):

Install Linux Subsystem and try... Solved for me.

Answer (score -1):

This command works with out any issues. I was getting the same issue https://iam.amazonaws.com/

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)

I'm able to proceed with this command eg:

```
aws iam list-users "--no-verify-ssl"
```

Answer (score -2):

`aws configure set default.ca_bundle <your CA file>`

Answer (score -2):

Potentially this could be because AWS private keys were exposed.

Update to the latest version of AWS CLI from here to resolve this issue.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Answer (score -4):

I agree with above answers, do the following

1- Remove your cli and install latest cli

2- check the certificate exist: C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\botocore\cacert.pem

3- if it doesn't exist remove the cli and go to: C:\Program Files\ and remove Amazon

4- Install cli latest version it should work.

5- Try testing with your VPN connected

Answer (score -7):

use the following option to overcome the ssl certification issue.

aws s3 ls --no-verify-ssl

Comment: I used `aws s3 ls help` to see the format, and there is no option that you mentioned, but somehow it works to bypass SSL certificate verification.

Comment: Although this might make the error go away, disabling ssl verification is almost always a *very* bad thing to do. Instead, try to find and fix the reason that it failed (such as missing certificate files).