# AWS ec2 userdata ssl verify error.. unique

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, aws-cli, user-data

So I created my own vanilla centos image and installed the aws cli tools. All commands including s3 work fine as either ec2-user or root.

My issue: For some reason only when I launch a server, in the user data I'm doing just a simple aws s3 cp command I get the ssl_verify_certificate error.

Understand userdata runs as root. I've reinstalled the tools still no same issue. Any help would be appreciated

Running Centos 7.9

Comment: hi perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946050/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-in-aws-cli

Comment: thanks but like I mentioned  the commands work fine when I log in run the commands as the same user without the ssl-verify error

Comment: perhaps use the `ec2-user` instead of root, since that has the cert chain

Comment: Can you edit your Question to provide a simple script that we can use to reproduce the error?