# After upgrading AWSCLIV2, aws-cli broke

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

After upgrading AWS cli

```
msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
```

aws cli broke on `windows 10`, `aws-cli/2.3.7 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off`

```
SSL validation failed for https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)
```

However same version installed on WSL2 works perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you know if you're using an HTTP proxy on your network? Also, this will sound strange, but make sure that your `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\config` profiles are configured as `[profile xxx]` rather than just `[xxx]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED in aws cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946050/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-in-aws-cli) And one more helpful [article](https://www.shellhacks.com/aws-cli-ssl-validation-failed-solved/)

Comment: Solved:  Problem was different. It was due to a service "cisco umbrella" which caused this SSL error.