# SSL validation failed for https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I installed AWS cli version 2 & also configure /AWS configure with access key ,sec..key
I am trying to access aws resource from the windows cmd OR PowerShell but i am getting this error!

Please any one have better way to solve this issue!

[image: error image]

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946050/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-in-aws-cli